# Project Based Learning or Applied Math involving modular arithmetics?

Tags: problem-design, inquiry-based-learning

I am searching for ideas to construct Project Based Learning type that involves Modular arithmetics with eventually geometry and could fit in High School level

What could a nice research question for a project that could explored which requires the use of modular arithmetics?

Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Rotations of regular polygons.

Start with an equilateral triangle. Label the vertices one, two, three. Define a rotation to be 60° counterclockwise, for example (or you could go clockwise). Note that the locations of the vertices have shifted. Consider this a new “state“ or “configuration”.

Now, what “configuration” does one end up with after *n* rotations?

Then, extend this to any n-sided polygon. A real life application would be modeling the movement of molecules. Gallian’s abstract algebra book shows a cross-section of a 28-sided HIV virus, for example. Or, how about rendering graphics in video games? Modeling movements of satellites and space shuttles in outer space?

A more accessible example would be a clock, or days of the week.

Incidentally, you could then use mod 12 or mod 7 to discuss notes on musical scales.

Comment: Thx. Very interesting ideas. I can see how it could be applied to rotation of figures as you explained. Same also with clock.  the 28-sided HIV virus, graphic in video games, and movement of satellites => I have been checking NASA website, and google with little success.  I ll keep searching.

Answer (score 1):

I think the idea of check digits is pretty compelling.  A bunch of examples of where check digits are used can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_digit), including things like government ID numbers in various countries, UPC and ISBN codes, credit cards, etc.  The basic idea is that you're given a number, say an ISBN number on a book.  You'd like to know if the number you've been given is a valid ISBN number.  What you do is calculate a certain (weighted) sum of all the numbers in the ISBN except the check digit (the last digit in the ISBN number, it takes on 11 values from 0 to X) and reduce the total mod 11.  If the result is not equal to the check digit, then you were not given a valid ISBN number.  If they're equal it might be inconclusive.  What's more, in many cases, the procedure can also identify what kind of error occurred and where.